# how to binding ICommand from MainWindow Class in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I am try to Binding a ICommand property on a Button Command from MainWindow. But it`s not working.
Here is sample code which I try for this.

C# Code :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ICommand _StartButtonCommand;

    public ICommand StartButtonCommand
    {
        get{ return this._StartButtonCommand;}
        set 
        {
            if (this._StartButtonCommand!=value)
            {
                this._StartButtonCommand = value;
            }
        }
    }
     public MainWindow()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.StartButtonCommand = new ReplayCommand(new Action<object>(startButtonCommandEx));
     }
     private void startButtonCommandEx(object obj)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Done");
     }

    protected class ReplayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _action;

        public ReplayCommand(Action<object> action)
        {
            this._action = action;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            try
            {
                if (parameter!=null)
                {
                    this._action(parameter);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "AutoShutdown", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML :

```
 <Button x:Name="buttonStrat" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="84.274" Height="39.246" Command="{Binding StartButtonCommand, ElementName=window}"/>
```

Actually I want to access UI Elements Like DataGridView SelectedItem Property or any other UI property using ICommand that`s why i am writing ICommand in MainWindow Class.
 I don`t know this is right way or wrong way. I just try it and i am not success. If it is wrong way please advice me what is right way and how to do it.

Thank`s for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you didn't set the `DataContext` on the button:

```
buttonStrat.DataContext = this;
```

And in the xaml use this:

```
Command="{Binding StartButtonCommand}"
```

Also to make your code shorter you could change your property to this:

```
public ICommand StartButtonCommand
{
    get { return new ReplayCommand(new Action<object>(startButtonCommandEx)); }
}
```